# Using odeint on multidimensional array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, differential-equations, odeint

I would like to apply odeint to an array of initial conditions and return a derivative that has the same size as those initial conditions. I could loop over each initial condition, but I think that will be very slow with higher N. The example below is from the [docs for odeint](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html). sol_1 works as expected, but sol_2 gives the error `ValueError: Initial condition y0 must be one-dimensional.`

Does anyone have a clever solution for how to make sol_2 run without just looping over each initial condition? Thanks.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def pend(y, t, b, c):
    theta, omega = y
    dydt = [omega, -b*omega - c*np.sin(theta)]
    return dydt

b = 0.25
c = 5.0
t = np.linspace(0, 10, 101)

#   0D initial values, directly from docs
y0_1 = [np.pi - 0.1, 0]
sol_1 = odeint(pend, y0_1, t, args=(b, c))

#   1D initial values, directly from docs
y0_2 = [np.ones((3)) * (np.pi - 0.1), np.zeros((3))]

#   Error here
sol2 = odeint(pend, y0_2, t, args=(b, c))
```

Comment: Flatten `y0_2` so it is 1d as required.  `pend` has to return a 1d array of the same size.

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't look that neat because I'm passing N, but it does solve the problem. I posted a solution based on your comment.

Comment: See also odeintw, which was created to systematically treat such situations. In general it is a bad idea to combine the integration of several eventually very different solutions. It tends to combine the worst properties of each numerical solution in regard to the step size selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is essentially the same answer written by OP, but I think it might be a little cleaner. First, I used the `flatten` method, which isn't as verbose as the `np.ndarray.flatten` function. Second, I flatten the results to pass to the ODE function, reshape inside the function for extracting values and using, and then flatten the result for the return. At the very end, I use `np.split` to extract each of the solutions.

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def pend(y, t, b, c, N):
    theta, omega = y.reshape(-1,N)
    dydt = np.stack([omega, -b*omega - c*np.sin(theta)])
    return dydt.flatten()

b = 0.25
c = 5.0
t = np.linspace(0, 10, 101)

# Number of inputs
N = 3

# 1D initial values, directly from docs
theta0 = np.ones((N,)) * (np.pi - 0.1)
omega0 = np.zeros((N,))
y0_2 = np.stack([theta0, omega0])

#   Flattened version of the inputs
y0_2f = y0_2.flatten()

# Run altered pend (pend2) with flattened inputs
sol_2 = odeint(pend, y0_2f, t, args=(b, c, N))
sols_split = np.split(sol_2, N, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the comment from hpaulj I came up with a solution. It's not very pretty because I'm passing N, but it does work and it's almost definitely better than looping. This should work N dimensional inputs as well, it would just require reshaping back to the original shape at the end.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def pend(y, t, b, c):
    theta, omega = y
    dydt = [omega, -b*omega - c*np.sin(theta)]
    return dydt

def pend2(y, t, b, c, N):
    theta = y[:N]
    omega = y[N:]
    dydt = [omega, -b*omega - c*np.sin(theta)]
    dydt = np.ndarray.flatten(np.array(dydt))
    return dydt

b = 0.25
c = 5.0
t = np.linspace(0, 10, 101)

#   0D initial values, directly from docs
y0_1 = [np.pi - 0.1, 0]
sol_1 = odeint(pend, y0_1, t, args=(b, c))

#   1D initial values, directly from docs
theta0 = np.ones((3)) * (np.pi - 0.1)
omega0 = np.zeros((3))
y0_2 = [theta0, omega0]

#   Flattened version of the inputs
y0_2f = np.ndarray.flatten(np.array(y0_2))

#   Number of inputs
N = len(theta0)

#   Run altered pend (pend2) with flattened inputs
sol_2 = odeint(pend2, y0_2f, t, args=(b, c, N))
```